# History behind the formation of "passé simple"

Tags: grammaire, étymologie, histoire

At school, when we first learned about "le passé simple" my teacher would tell us that most of the verbs in the third group can be formed by taking the root from "le participe passé", e.g.

> conclure -->  conclu --> je conclus
>
> courir --> couru --> je courus

However, there are many exceptions to this, e.g.

> naître --> né --> je naquis
>
> battre --> battu --> je battis

My question is where do these irregular forms come from? How do you get *naquis* from *naître* for example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D'abord les verbes appartenant au 3<sup>e</sup> groupe de conjugaison sont des verbes dits *irréguliers*. Qu'il soit impossible de trouver des règles les impliquant tous communément dans la formation de quoi que ce soit ne peut être que... fatal.

Ce que nous appelons *passé composé* (l'association d'un auxiliaire et du participe passé) est une innovation linguistique qui nous vient du gallo-roman. D'abord formé sur l'association du verbe avoir conjugué associé au participe passé latin : *J'ai bu -> Habeo bibitum*. Plus tard, et par nécessité d'utiliser ce temps avec des verbes pronominaux, viendra l'auxiliaire être

Le gallo-roman se retrouve alors avec deux façons d'exprimer le passé, son *passé composé* et le parfait du latin qui subsiste et deviendra *notre* passé simple.

Sauf... que cela ne va pas partout sans problème ni risque de confusion.
Il existe en latin des verbes dits *déponents* (verbes de sens actif mais de forme passive) que le latin classique conjugue au parfait de façon furieusement similaire à *notre passé composé*. C'est par exemple le cas de votre *naître* qui au parfait donnait : *nat(us/a/um) sum, es, est...*

*notre* passé simple a donc, dans ces cas (et quibusdam allis) dû chercher sa racine ailleurs. Dans ce cas précis, on a pris l'infinitif (*nasci*) auquel on a collé les désinences caractéristiques du parfait latin : (-i, -isti, -it, -imus, -istis, -erunt.) à l'origine des désinences de *notre* passé simple.

<sub>NDaCOSwt : Je tiens la distinction actif/passif pour fondatrice de 90% de ce que l'on appelle grammaire. Ainsi, me permets-je de tenir 90% des *irrégularités* / *alogismes* pour causés par cette disjonction qui concerne une *borderline* sans cesse croissante. (Et c'est le Bien!)</sub>

Comment: Très bonne réponse, merci !

Answer (score 2):

Soit dit en passant, ayant lu ces deux bonnes réponses je te propose de lire cet article exhaustif (?)

http://gerbert.e.g.f.unblog.fr/files/2008/11/passsimplepasscomposunpeudhistoire.pdf

sur l'histoire du passé simple et du passé composé.

Il y a également le lemme de la wikipédia.

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass%C3%A9_simple_en_fran%C3%A7ais

Answer (score 1):

Je suppose que le changement est le plus souvent, sinon toujours, fondé sur la racine latine ou grecque lorsque il n'est pas dicté par la fin de l'infinitif du verbe ; dans le cas de « naitre » le « qu » est la restitution du « c » dans le latin « nascere ».

[Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/na%C3%AEtre) Bourg. nâtre ; provenç. nascer, naisser : cat. naixer ; esp. nacer ; port. nascer, nacer ; ital. nascere ; du bas-lat. nascere, dérivé de nasci.

D'après [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass%C3%A9_simple_en_fran%C3%A7ais) il n'y aurait pas un grand nombre d'exceptions

Le passé simple se forme principalement selon trois cas :

Cas principaux ⇒ Forme induite au passé simple

participe passé en -é   ⇒ passé simple en -a  
participe passé en -i    ⇒ passé simple en -i  
(passé simple aussi en -i) participe passé en -ert + verbes en -dre (sauf -oudre)  + faire + voir + battre + vaincre + vêtir + coudre
participe passé en -u  mourir  ⇒ passé simple en -u

Cas particuliers : avoir, être, tenir/venir (et dérivés), naître.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse !